# CMake linking and by-products in build directory

Tags: cmake, build, linker, libraries

I'm new to CMake. Therefore, I have several questions which I don't want to split into separate threads, because they are fairly small and related. Long story short, let's look at this linking invocation:

```
/D/Software/MinGW/bin/g++.exe   -fmessage-length=0 -mfpmath=sse -msse2 -msse3 -mssse3 -msse4 -fopenmp -g    -Wl,--whole-archive CMakeFiles/go.dir/objects.a -Wl,--no-whole-archive  -o go.exe -Wl,--out-implib,libgo.dll.a -Wl,--major-image-version,0,--minor-image-version,0  /D/Software/Qt/4.8.0/lib/libQtOpenGLd4.a /D/Software/Qt/4.8.0/lib/libQtGuid4.a /D/Software/Qt/4.8.0/lib/libQtCored4.a -lglu32 -lopengl32 -lkernel32 -luser32 -lgdi32 -lwinspool -lshell32 -lole32 -loleaut32 -luuid -lcomdlg32 -ladvapi32
```

1. Why CMake tends to add **compile options** to **link options**? For
   instance, SSE options are simply irrelevant in this case.
2. Why does
       it link me with some weird libraries `kernel32, winspool, shell32,
       ole32, uuid, comdlg32, advapi32`? When I was building the same
       project with QMake - there were none of these libraries. Moreover, I
       don't even know the purpose of these ones. So, it looks like these
       libraries are redundant, or am I wrong?
3. I can't see the list of linked **object files**. However,  I notice
       this `-Wl,--whole-archive CMakeFiles/go.dir/objects.a
       -Wl,--no-whole-archive  -o go.exe -Wl,--out-implib,libgo.dll.a` part which is unknown to me. But, I guess that all object files are
       somehow archived into objects.a, and therefore this part of linking
       essentially is the same as the explicit list of object files, isn't it?
4. I guess I don't have to worry about that, but I'm curious about the
   build folder - so much garbage out there:

[image]

Is it intended behavior of CMake to produce so many by-products of build process? Also I'm completely confused about `a.exe` - what's that? Why should it ever reside in my build directory?

Comment: Could it also be a by-product of MinGW/GCC? It is fairly common to use g++ as a frontend to the linker with -Wl options getting passed along to the actual linker...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

wrt 4)

The a.exe files (or more specifically the folders the reside in) look like binaries CMake used to determine the existence of certain compiler features.

In any case the amount of files you have there looks perfectly fine for CMake. Some of them are really useful for advanced debugging if something in the configuration and build process failed and I think its hence a good practice of CMake to keep them alive.